PyCharm Python Packages Tool install/uninstall package button missed, and documentation does not displayed
I can't find install/uninstall button in [Python Packages] tool.
Documentation also not loaded, however from Settings->Project:any->Python Interpreter I can install packages and also docs loaded.


Any idea how to fix this issue?
